# Using Keras ImageDataGenerator for Images for data with more than 3 channels

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, neural-network

I work with 200x200 pixel images with 35 channels.
How is it possible to use the Keras `ImageDataGenerator` for data with more than 3 channels?

I want to rotate, chop, brighten, etc these images for my CNN using the `fit_generator` command.
However, the `ImageDataGenerator` only supports up to 4 channels and throws the error:

`ValueError: Unsupported channel number: 35`

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Comment: I don't believe such a thing is supported

Comment: You need to create your own generator (see [Sequence](https://keras.io/utils/)) in which you apply augmentations manually. You can use `cv2`, it works in more channels, another library that should do great augmentations is Albumentations (but I don't know whether it supports multiple channels).