# Getting an error saying " could not broadcast input array from shape (19,761,3) into shape (19,761,1227,3)" while building a CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am working on an image classification problem where I have to deal with input images of 19 channels. I was successful in doing it with normal 3 channel or greyscale images but I am getting the following error when I changed my code and model to be trained upon 19 channeled inputs.

> could not broadcast input array from shape (19,761,3) into shape (19,761,1227,3)

This is my code

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 761, 1227

train_data_dir = '/home/spectrograms/train'
validation_data_dir = '/home/spectrograms/test'
nb_train_samples = 814
nb_validation_samples = 134
epochs = 50
batch_size = 32



if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (19, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height,19)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(19, img_width, img_height), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), border_mode='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0,
    zoom_range=0,
    horizontal_flip=False)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(19,img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(19,img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('/home/rahul/Roshan/CNN/Saved_models_13/custom/CNN_model.h5')
```

Comment: Review the comment here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435010/using-keras-imagedatagenerator-for-images-for-data-with-more-than-3-channels

Comment: Your model requires input in shape (1,19,761,1227) ... as follows: model(tf.random.uniform((1,19,img_width,img_height))) ... results in <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.67745835, 0.32254168]], dtype=float32)> ... therefore check your input, does it have a correct shape?

Comment: ...where note that the first dimension is the batch ... for example input may be also model(tf.random.uniform((4,19,img_width,img_height))) ...resulitng in a result of shape (4,2), etc. By following this principle you will find a solution your problem.